# What dose the error code meaning of mac kernel-extension?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

I was program a kernel extension about tun on mac, I use a API `proto_register_plumber` like follows:

```
err = proto_register_plumber(PF_INET, IFNET_FAMILY_TUN, method_attach, method_detach);
if (err) {
    printf("error code is : %d\n", err);
}
```

On one mac(10.13), it return 17, what it means? how can i fix it?

I read about the API doc on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1532491-proto_register_plumber?language=objc, but i do not found anything about what the error code means.

Answer (score 1):

`17` is almost certainly an `errno`, especially as this is from the BSD portion of the KPI. If you look in [errno.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/sys/errno.h.auto.html) you will find that it corresponds to `EEXIST`:

```
#define EEXIST      17      /* File exists */
```

In the context of your API call, this probably means there already is something registered for the thing you're trying to register. I'm not familiar with the `proto_register_plumber()` function, but a very quick look at [its source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/net/kpi_protocol.c.auto.html) reveals the following check near the start of the function, which appears to confirm my suspicion:

```
lck_mtx_lock(proto_family_mutex);

TAILQ_FOREACH(proto_family, &proto_family_head, proto_fam_next) {
    if (proto_family->proto_family == protocol_family &&
        proto_family->if_family == interface_family) {
        lck_mtx_unlock(proto_family_mutex);
        return (EEXIST);
    }
}
```

Could it be that:

- You have previously registered the handler, unloaded your kext, which did not unregister it, and then you have reloaded your kext, trying to register it again? In this case, a reboot (and fixing your kext stop function!) should fix it.
- Another loaded kext already registers its own handler? If so, try unloading the likely candidates.
- The xnu kernel already provides a default handler for this protocol family? Maybe you need to go about what you're trying to do in a different way.

Comment: Tanks, it's because another kext registers its handler!